# python configparser alias for sections in ini files

Tags: python, configparser

In my *.ini files I have sections like these:

```
[server-a]
applicationkey = <keyid>
xuserid = <userid>
host = <full host with paths>
:
[server-b]
applicationkey = <keyid>
xuserid = <userid>
host = <full host with paths>
:
```

How can I add section [server-test] to use the same key-value pairs as [server-b]
if I add an empty [server-test] above [server-b] it fallsback to [DEFAULT]

```
[server-test]
default=server-b
```

does not work

with ExtendedInterpolation() I can substitute, but not section=section:

```
[server-test]
applicationkey = ${server-a:applicationkey}
xuserid = ${server-a:xuserid}
host = ${server-a:host}
```

Works but this is like cut and paste.

```
[service-test]
service-test = ${server-a}
```

does not work

Comment: Need to alias many sections not only default